# PHP (yii2) console script stops working right in the middle of the execution process

Tags: php, postgresql, loops, yii2, console

I have a console script (inside yii2 application) for changing user's usernames in DB (postgreSQL) and writing changelog data to csv-file. I use for loop to do changes in bulks of 100 users through offset.

```
    public function actionTest()
{
    $query = User::find()->where(['username' => '']);
    $total = $query->count(); // SQL variant - SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = ''
    $data = [];
    $filePath = '/path/to/folder/log.csv';
    for ($offset = 0; $offset <= $total; $offset += 100) {
        /** @var User[] $users */
        $users = $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->limit(100)->offset($offset)->all(); // SQL variant - SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '' ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            User::updateAll(['username' => 'newUsername'], ['id' => $user->id]); // SQL variant - UPDATE user SET username = 'newUsername' WHERE id = 1
            $data[] = ['username' => 'newUsername']; // collect data to generate csv-file in the future
        }
        $csvObj = new CSV(); // "mnshankar/csv": "1.8"
        $csvObj->with($data, false, 'a+')->put($filePath, 'a+');
        $data = [];
    }
}
```

The problem is that this script stops getting data from DB right in the middle of total amount of users, so i get 0 items in $users array.

For example, if i have $total = 15000, it stops working after itteration with $offset = 7500,
if $total = 7500, it stops working after itteration with $offset = 3800, if $total = 3800, it stops working after itteration with $offset = 1900 etc.

I tried to write simple test for this loop with pg_* function and it works properly:

```
    public function actionPgTest()
{
    $dbConnection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=8080 dbname=user_db user=some_guy password=some_pass");
    $total = pg_query($dbConnection,'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = \'\'');
    $total = pg_fetch_array($total)['count'];

    for ($offset = 0; $offset <= $total; $offset += 100) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = \'\' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET ' . $offset;
        $users = pg_query($dbConnection,$query);
        $users = pg_fetch_all($users);
        sleep(3);
    }
    pg_close();
}
```

Also, I tried to do this with bash-script and it also works properly:

```
#!/bin/bash count_query="select count(*) FROM \"user\" WHERE username = ''" count=$(echo $count_query | psql -U user -Atq user_db) query_base="select id FROM \"user\" WHERE username = '' LIMIT 100 OFFSET " for offset in $(seq 0 100 $count); do  echo $query_base$offset| psql -U user -Atq  user_db   sleep 3; done;
```

Also, I tried run script without generating csv-file and got the same problem right in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It continues and will return empty data, due to offset is set same as total records.

Here if offset meaning from postgreSQL docs:

> OFFSET says to skip that many rows before beginning to return rows.
>   OFFSET 0 is the same as omitting the OFFSET clause. If both OFFSET and
>   LIMIT appear, then OFFSET rows are skipped before starting to count
>   the LIMIT rows that are returned.

Also read it from here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: Not really. I added offset data to stdout to see it in console every itteration and it always less then total amount of users untill the end of script. Also i added users' count data to stdout and every time got something like this:

Total users' count = 15000, current users' count = 100, current offset = 100
Total users' count = 15000, current users' count = 100, current offset = 200
...
Total users' count = 15000, current users' count = 100, current offset = 7500
Total users' count = 15000, current users' count = 0, current offset = 7600
and from this moment there is no data in query

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was in OFFSET and LIMIT (devprashant's comment helps a lot).
For example we have table with 6 items with minus in every:

1. -
2. -
3. -
4. -
5. -
6. -

For the 1st itteration we have OFFSET = 0 and LIMIT = 2 and are changing the 1st 2 minus for pluses to get:

1. +
2. +
3. -
4. -
5. -
6. -

The 2nd itteration will be with OFFSET = 2 and LIMIT = 2 and we get the items with id = 5 and id = 6. Thanks to offset the query result starts from the id = 5 and limits for 2 items. So we get:

1. +
2. +
3. -
4. -
5. +
6. +

That's how we get arithmetic progression and are out of items till the middle of total amount of items.

Working solution:

```
public function actionTest(){
    $query = User::find()->where(['username' => '']);
    $idsQuery = clone $query;
    $userIds = $idsQuery->select(['id'])->limit(1000000)->asArray(true)->indexBy('id')->all();
    $userIds = array_keys($userIds);
    asort($userIds);
    $total = count($userIds);
    $data = [];
    $filePath = '/path/to/folder/log.csv';
for ($offset = 0; $offset <= $total; $offset += 100) {
    $query = User::find()->where(['id' => array_slice($userIds , $offset, 100)]);
    $users = $query->all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        User::updateAll(['username' => 'newUsername'], ['id' => $user->id]); // SQL variant - UPDATE user SET username = 'newUsername' WHERE id = 1
        $data[] = ['username' => 'newUsername']; // collect data to generate csv-file in the future
    }
    $csvObj = new CSV(); // "mnshankar/csv": "1.8"
    $csvObj->with($data, false, 'a+')->put($filePath, 'a+');
    $data = [];
}}
```

Comment: @devprashant upvoted it but didn't mark as accepted cause the main answer is wrong and the link to documentation helped. So, to not mislead others, i didn't do this. And thank you for help!